# What is wrong? Does it have to do with a pointer?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pointers

My WinMain starts like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    if(SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        {
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;

            Game game;

            D2DResources d2DResources;

            game.SetPointer(d2DResources);
            hr = d2DResources.Initialize(hInst);
```

My compiler will execute the line shown above last before breaking for an unandled exception. I know it wont go further since I have added a MessageBox command right before hr = d2DResources.Initialize(hInst) and another one right after, and only the first showed up.

So, D2DResources::Initialisize(HINSTANCE) looks like this:

```
HRESULT D2DResources::Initialize(HINSTANCE hInst)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    // Create factory
    hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pD2DFactory);

    // Create WIC factory
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&pIWICIF)
            );
    }

    // Create a window class
    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    ZeroMemory(&wClass,sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wClass.cbClsExtra=NULL;
    wClass.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.cbWndExtra=NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIcon=NULL;
    wClass.hIconSm=NULL;
    wClass.hInstance=hInst;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc=WinProc;
    wClass.lpszClassName="Window Class";
    wClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    wClass.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,"Failed to register window class","Window Class Failed",MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    m_hWnd=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            "Window Class",
            "Game", // Replace with gameName
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_MAXIMIZE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            hInst,
            this);

    if(!m_hWnd)
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,"Window class creation failed","Window Class Failed",MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(m_hWnd,&rc);

    // Creates render target
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
            D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(
                m_hWnd,
                D2D1::SizeU(
                    rc.right - rc.left,
                    rc.bottom - rc.top)),
                &pRT);
    }

    D2D1_SIZE_F pRTSize = pRT->GetSize();
    RECT rect = {50, (long)pRTSize.height-(LogLineSize*5), (long)pRTSize.width, (long)pRTSize.height};
    logArea = rect;

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pRT->CreateSolidColorBrush(
            D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White),
            &pWhiteBrush
            );
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = DWriteCreateFactory(
            DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
            __uuidof(pWF),
            reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&pWF)
            );
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pWF->CreateTextFormat(
            L"Verdana",
            NULL,
            DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
            DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
            DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
            14.0f,
            L"",
            &pTextFormat
            );
    }

    return hr;
}
```

And Game::SetPointer, which is overloaded, looks like this when called with a D2DResources object:

```
void Game::SetPointer(D2DResources& p)
{
    pD2DResources=&p;
}
```

pD2DResources is a D2DResources*.

The problem happens during D2DResources::Initialization(HINSTANCE) when a WM_SIZE message is sent to my WinProc. So, there is some of my WinProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(msg==WM_CREATE)
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
            Game* pGame = (Game*)pcs->lpCreateParams;

            ::SetWindowLongPtrW(
                hWnd,
                GWLP_USERDATA,
                PtrToUlong(pGame)
                );
    }
    else
    {
        Game* pGame = reinterpret_cast<Game*>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
            ::GetWindowLongPtrW(
                hWnd,
                GWLP_USERDATA
                )));

        switch(msg)
        {

        case WM_SIZE:
            {
                UINT width = LOWORD(lParam);
                UINT height = HIWORD(lParam);
                pGame->pD2DResources->OnResize(width, height);
            }
            break;
```

When OnResize is called, the problem happens.

```
void D2DResources::OnResize(UINT width, UINT height)
{
    if(pRT)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pRT->Resize(D2D1::SizeU(width, height));
        if(hr!=0) MessageBox(NULL,"Render target could not be resized","ID2D1HwndRenterTarget Error",MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

The compiler breaks and there is a yellow arrow pointing at the if(pRT) (pRT being a pointer to a render target) line.

Interestingly, looking at autos during debugging shows this.

- this    0x00000000 {log=0x00000000  nLogLines=??? logArea={...} ...}   D2DResources * const
- log 0x00000000     wchar_t [511]
      nLogLines   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
- logArea {top=??? bottom=??? left=??? right=???} tagRECT
      m_hWnd  CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
      pD2DFactory CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
      pIWICIF CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
      pWF CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
      pRT CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
      pCurrentScreen  CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
      pWhiteBrush CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
      pTextFormat CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found

So, what is the problem, and what is the solution?

Comment: `Something is freaking wrong, perhaps with a pointer` is probably the worst title to a "question" on here, that I've ever seen...

Comment: Rough guess... `pGame->pD2DResources` is null?

Comment: This question gave me cancer.

Comment: pRT is NULL, or so I believe, I do know how to know that.

@VoidKing Is it because of the "freaking"? Should I edit that?

Comment: @Mickael Well, actually I was referring to the fact that it is not in the form of a question, mostly, but the "freaking" doesn't help. It denotes (inaccurate or not) that it is posted in somewhat of an "agitated" state, and on here, as that happens all the time, it could easily be purposefully avoided or taken under the wrong context.

Comment: `WinProc` never checks if `lParam` or anything else is equal to `nullptr`, and it definitely should.  At least `assert`.

Comment: @Mickael Also, it clearly doesn't describe the problem in the slightest and that's probably the worst part.

Comment: @Mickael LOL, that title's not much better, but at least you're trying :) Try using a question that describes the problem/platform/language, something. It is the very nature of your asking a question that denotes that "something is wrong"

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron `pRT` isn't null, `Game::pD2DResources` is.

Comment: Won't Game::SetPointer give that pointer the value I want it to take? What should I do instead, and why what I tried doesn't work?

Comment: As for assert checking for nullptr, I tried this but it won't work. What should I do instead?

assert(lParam!=nullptr) and assert(lParam!=(LPARAM)nullprt) both won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the wrong pointer to your window. You're creating the window in `D2DResources::Initialize` and passing `this` as the `lpParam`, but in the window procedure you're casting it to a `Game*`.

Comment: Alright. I will try that but there is one more issue. D2DResources objects need a HWND to operate. How will I have its functions work with Game's WHND? Is it by using pointers?

Comment: Either refactor your code to create the window from a function in your `Game` class, or (simpler) pass a pointer to your `Game` structure to the `D2DResources::Initialize` function and use that for the `lpParam` value for the window.

Answer (score 3):

By the time the WinProc is called, the D2DResources object you declared in the WinMain has gone out of scope, but you are still holding a pointer to it.  When you call a method through the pointer, it is being executed against a spot in the stack that no longer points to a D2DResources object (note-- your MessageBox's are misleading you-- it really has gone out of scope.)

Simplest way to fix this is to change

```
D2DResources d2DResources;
```

in your WinMain to

```
D2DResources& d2DResources = *(new D2DResources());
```

which will put the same object on the heap.

Although I wouldn't swear that's the only problem with your code...

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying that right away.

Comment: Always best to try the answer first before accepting it, since I think you'll find that's not actually the cause of your problems in this case.

Comment: I'm upvoting that only because of the last line.

Comment: binding dynamic memory to a reference like this doesn't seem like a good idea....

Comment: Note that the OP hasn't shown enough code to know if the D2DResources object is actually going out of scope - he may be running his message loop within the `if SUCCEEDED(...` in which case that wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @Johnathan Potter -- you're right, probably recast problem you pointed out

Comment: It should stay in scope since at some point there is a while loop into WinMain